# Search text through multiple multi-line text

Tags: grep

I am using `aplay -L` which list out multiple device and it's description.

```
$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
```

where `null`, `hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0`, `surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0` are device name. I want to search pattern through device name and it's description and find device name matching it's description.

My expectation is

```
aplay -L | pattern_match_command "Surround output"
```

will return `surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0`
Similarly

```
aplay -L | pattern_match_command "pulse"
```

will return `pulse`.

Basically context of each device is

```
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
```

Currently I am using line processing which does not cover description.

```
aplay -L | grep "pulse"
```

Any hint what tool I can use. I am using `ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: Have you looked up `grep` and its man page?

Comment: @NasirRiley I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686705/8595891) answer on StackOverflow which says `grep` is not sufficient. It recommended `pcregrep` which requires external installation.

Comment: `grep` will return both results in your question. If you need to use Perl-compatible regular expressions, `grep` has a `-P` switch that does that.

Comment: The output shown in your edit appears not to come from the command that you are showing.  I can only recreate that output if I change the single quotes around the `awk` code to double quotes.  Note that the only `print` statement is `print dev` and that `dev` will get a value as the first character on a line is non-blank. This means that either 1) `$0` is being interpreted by the _shell_ (due to double quoting of the code), or that 2) `aplay -L` is producing its output with indentation (which my version of that utility does not do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU grep having the PCRE support

```
mygrep() {
## helper  variables to make writing of regex tractable:-

## any nonwhitespace char which is not a colon
noncolon='(?:(?!:)\S)'
nonequal='(?:(?!=)\S)'

# these occur in the description line after the colon, akin to key=value pairs
pair="${nonequal}+=${nonequal}+"

# a header line comprises a run of noncolon nonwhitespace optionally followed by pairs
hdr="${noncolon}+(?::(?:,?${pair})+)?"

# description line is one that begins with a space and has atleast one nonwhitespace
descline='(?:\s.*\S.*\n)'

# supply your string to search for in the description section here ( case insensitive)
srch=$1
t=$(mktemp)

aplay -L | tee "$t" \
| grep -Pzo \
 "(?im)^${hdr}\n(?=${descline}*\h.*\Q${srch}\E)" \
| tr -d '\0' \
| grep . ||
grep -iF -- "$1" "$t"
}

## now invoke mygrep with the search string
mygrep  'card=pch'
```

Outputs:-

```
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works out of the box. It will be awesome if you can provide some explanation as well.

Comment: @Pranjal Doshi updated with a brief comment about the regexes.

Comment: This does not work if `=` is part of search expression eg. `CARD=PCH`

Comment: I have updated the answer to take care if the = in search string.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```bsh
aplay -L |
pat='surround' awk '
    BEGIN { pat = tolower(ENVIRON["pat"]) }
    /^[^[:blank:]]/ { dev = $0; next }
    tolower($0) ~ pat { print dev }'
```

This `awk` command would remember each line that starts with a non-blank character in the variable `dev`.  Whenever some other line matches a given pattern, the `dev` variable's value is outputted.

The pattern is passed in via an environment variable, `pat`.  This is converted to lower-case and stored in the `awk` variable `pat`.  When the pattern is matched against a line, the line is also converted to lower-case, so the pattern matching is in this sense case insensitive.

The output from the command above, given your example data, would be

```
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
```

due to matching the word `surround` in the line

```
4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. `awk`  will work in my case. I've not accepted as regex needs to be updated and not working out of the box. I Will update the answer with the pattern.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi Well, you can use whatever extended regular expression that you want in place of my simple string `surround` which was just an example. If you had some other issue with specifying a regular expression, I'd be more than happy to explain or look into it.

Comment: Added output in edit of question.. Getting bunch of empty lines even though device is present. I think it's because of `/^[^[:blank:]]`.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi I can't recreate that behavior on an Ubuntu system with `aplay` and GNU `awk`, unless I use double quotes instead of single quotes around the `awk` code (which is not what I have in my answer, and not what you are showing in your edit).